# How do I make a website do things at certain times?

Tags: php, server, automation

For example:

Your website has some kind of statistics for every user that need to be updated every night at midnight regardless of whether the user is logged in or not. The script that updates the statistics is called "update.php"

How would you make your web server execute update.php every night at 12pm?

Comment: that is called a cron job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tie the script to a cronjob on your server. To set up a cron job under **Linux** or **Unix** do the following:

Create a crontab file, with the following command:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Append an entry like the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/file/script.php
```

Numbers before the comand represent the time it will run. For example:

```
1: Minute (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Day (0-31)
4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
```

Comment: honestly Tony, that's a comment and of very low quality.

Comment: if you get dv for it, it would not have been me; I've no votes left ;-)

Comment: Perfect! For some reason I couldn't find any mention of cron jobs when searching for answers myself. Thank you!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry pal, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Tony Thanks Tony. I can *honestly* say that that was not my downvote and you've made a good edit :-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Tony I'll be glad to upvote your answer when I have votes left to do so.